# TinyMce Chrome newline issue

Tags: tinymce, google-chrome

Is anyone else having this issue. It is not possible to add a newline (line break `<br/>`, using 'enter') at the end of a text in tinymce. Only a ctrl + enter (paragraph) works. This problem only occurs in google chrome (v 39.0.2171.99).

Comment: Have you tried `SHIFT` + `ENTER`?

Comment: UPDATE: it seems like the paragraph tags are added (enter) but the visual editor is not placing the cursor on the next line. 
Again, this is only happening in google chrome. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Which OS do you have? I've seen various problems with Google Chrome combined with GBoard virtual keyboard on Android. This is because that combination emits events in non-traditional sequence (the events are still sensible but a lot of broken code expects different sequence and fail in random ways).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to add `<br>` in tinymce editor in vanilla wordpress is by ctrl + enter, there was never any other option unless you install a plugin for that.